Changing text colour in custom container in React Native
How do I change the text color and font in a custom container in react native?
I have a container file like so:
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View} from 'react-native';

const BoxContainer = props => {
    return (
        <View style={styles.boxContainer}>
        </View>
    );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    boxContainer:{
        shadowColor: '#000',
        shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 2 },
        shadowOpacity: 0.8,
        shadowRadius: 2,
        height:200,
        margin: 20,
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center'
    }
});

export default BoxContainer;

And a custom conainer component:

import React from 'react';
import { Button, StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import BoxContainer from './components/BoxContainer';
export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.page}>
      <BoxContainer style={styles.container1}>
          <Text>Box Content1</Text>
      </BoxContainer>
      <BoxContainer style={styles.container2}>
          <Text>Box Content2</Text>
      </BoxContainer>
      <BoxContainer style={styles.container3}>
          <View style={styles.button}>
            <Button title='Button' color='black'/>
          </View>
      </BoxContainer>
    </View>
  );
};
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  page:{
    flex:1,
    paddingTop:50
  },

  container1: {
    backgroundColor: 'yellow',
    height : 100
  },
  container2: {
    backgroundColor: 'red',
    height : 100
  },
  container3: {
    backgroundColor: 'grey',
    height : 100
  },
  button:{
    width:80,
    height:40,
    color: 'white',
    backgroundColor: 'white'
  }
});

Taken from this tutorial:
https://dzone.com/articles/custom-container-component-in-react-native-with-di
Grateful for any suggestions, please
